# laravel shared hosting view index not found error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

I uploaded the project written in laravel 9 to shared hosting.`View [home.index] not found.`
i am getting error.how can i solve?
.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

public>index.php

```
define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));



if (file_exists($maintenance = __DIR__.'/../storage/framework/maintenance.php')) {
    require $maintenance;
}



require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';



$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

$kernel = $app->make(Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Request::capture()
)->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please check:

1. is your DocumentRoot pointing to public directory of your app?
2. Do you have a <Directory "...."> section with correct settings?
   btw you should have there at least

   <Directory "....">
   Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
   AllowOverride all
   Allow all granted

You didn't mention if you are using an Alias or VirtualHost, but this applies to those configurations as well